# Cast object{Dictionary<string,object>} to List<Dictionary<string<object>>

Tags: c#

I try cast object to List<>. Actually i tried to cast object *testObj* which have type *object{...Dictionary \ }*  cast to list with name *testList* which have type *List\\>* but i have NULL as result, but *testObj* have information inside

```
List<Dictionary<string,object>> testList = (((Dictionary<string, object>)testObj)["key"]) as List<Dictionary<string, object>>;
```

Comment: if you look at `testObj["key"]` in the debugger, what type does it say it is?

Comment: It seems weird that if `testObj` is a dictionary as your cast indicates, that `testObj["key"]` would result in a list of those dictionaries.

Comment: @Jamiec : error CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

Comment: Where's the code where you assign a value to `testObj` or whatever `testObj` is referencing.

Comment: Ok, I meant `((Dictionary<string, object>)testObj)["key"]` as per your code. And where it says `object` when you do that there is a *real* type that it is

Comment: @Jamiec  object {System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>}

Comment: So if the object at that point is of type `Dictionary<string, object>` why are you trying to cast it to `List<Dictionary<string, object>>`? You cant magic a dictionary to a list of dictionaries!?

Comment: @Jamiec but i cant get value by index from object ? or can ?

Comment: Value by index doesnt make much sense for a dictionary. But you sort of can. `dict.ElementAt(0)`. This question is unclear what you're actually asking. Check the [help] for info on how to ask a good question.

Comment: It looks like what you want is `object value = ((Dictionary<string, object>)testObj)["key"];` I don't, however, know what the type of `object` is in your dictionary. Are you saying it's a `List<T>` of some kind?

Answer (score -1):

Use Linq:

```
   var testList = testObj.Select(kvp => kvp.Key).ToList();
```

Comment: What are you trying to show here? I don't understand what this line of code has to do with the question.